# how to switch values between integers?

Tags: c

So I need to switch between A and B without using another integer.

I was able to do this easily with a third integer (tmp). Is there any way to do this without it?

```
int a = 53, b = 12, tmp = 0;
tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

Comment: That is the proper way. Any other way may make the compiler miss an optimization, for example.

Comment: A better question is: is there ever a reason to switch between A and B without using another integer? I'd start with that one.

Comment: There is so many bundle of ways to do this: please refer all solutions, and its usage..[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-swap-two-numbers/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common mentioned method is:

```
y ^= x;
x ^= y;
y ^= x;
```

An alternative is to use addition and subtraction instead of XOR; but that's messy due to the risk of overflows.

*Note: To be precise; XOR causes undefined behavior for negative values (but that can be prevented with simple casts to unsigned and back to signed); and addition/subtraction can cause overflow which is also undefined behavior, but there's no easy fix for that.*

Of course no sane person would ever do this in real code (it's faster and cheaper to  use a temporary variable).

Comment: "XOR causes undefined behavior for negative values" Setting the sign bit with bitwise operators isn't necessarily undefined behavior. It is well-defined in case of `| & ^ ~` but undefined in case of `<<` and impl. defined in case of `>>`.

Comment: I'd add a warning that if `x` and `y` alias, this is not a no-op but set the. common, value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an other way to do it:

```
int a=53, b=12;
a = a + b; // a = 65
b = a - b; // b = 53
a = a - b; // a = 12
```

Comment: And what happens if the result of `a+b` overflows?

Comment: This method only works with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using arithmetic addition and subtraction between those two variables.

```
int a = 53, b = 12;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Comment: And what happens if the result of a+b overflows?